# How to find all combinations of two numbers in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

Let's say I have a list of four values. I want to find all combinations of two of the values. For example, I would like to get an output like:

```
((0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3))
```

As you can see, I do not want repetitions, for example (0, 1) and (1, 0)

This needs to be able to be used with larger numbers, not just 4, and I will have to iterate through all of the combos

I am using Python 3 and Windows, and this would ideally be an inbuilt function, a simple bit of list comprehension code, or something I can import. I have tried making this with range, but I do not know how to exclude the numbers that I have already done from it.

Comment: take a look at [combinations from itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: Ok sure, but did you give a chance to actually search for this problem in advance or do you assume the question is new? Do you have problems with a specific line in your code? `from itertools import combinations`
and `for i in combinations(range(4),2): print(i)` would be enough to create a generator and loop it.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I agree. However I did not find any good explaining answer to this question. It might be that the basics of it is already well-documented.

Answer (score 11):

It is very easy

```
from itertools import combinations
list(combinations([0,1,2,3],2))
```

Answer (score 3):

Take just the lower triangular matrix if you only need a distinct set

```
a = [1,2,10,20]
[(a[i], a[j+i+1]) for i in range(len(a))  for j in range(len(a[i+1:]))]

[(1, 2), (1, 10), (1, 20), (2, 10), (2, 20), (10, 20)]
```

Comment: sorry for the sloppy editing, it was my first post

Comment: NP, just mark all your code and hit **{}** this will mostly solve editing if you straight copy/paste from your editor

Comment: I think I fixed it now